# Python write to csv file one letter is assigned to each cell

Tags: python

I'm trying to give my csv file a title. I simply want to write a string of text into one cell as presented by excel.

But when I run this code:

```
with open(output_file, mode='w+') as csv_file:
    title_writer = csv.writer(csv_file,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    title_writer.writerow("AWS Instance List " + today)
```

The result is that each letter of the above occupies one cell instead of the whole thing appearing in one cell.

For example when I open up the csv file in excel this is what I see:

[image: Python csv problem]

What am I doing wrong? How can I correct this?

Comment: try enclosing your string in ```writerow``` in ```[]```

Comment: try `title_writer.writerow(["AWS Instance List " + today])` the problem is you're passing a string which is being iterated over, if you put it as a single element in a list then it will treat as a single value to write out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `[]` around what you pass to `writerow()` to make it a list.

```
with open(output_file, mode='w+') as csv_file:
    title_writer = csv.writer(csv_file,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    title_writer.writerow(["AWS Instance List " + today])
```